# How to exclude column while saving via jpa crud repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a pretty huge entity with many fields and a several methods which interacts with that entity. And I have some problem with non-repeatable read when tho threads read data from db at the same time, one thread changed a field and saved entity, but other one at the same time read data with old value didn't change it and saved. First solution that I thought was to change transaction isolation level to repeatable read, but it may take a huge influence on perfomance of my app. All I need is to ignore a field in the second method, but change it in first one, so @Transient annotation is not suittable here. in both cases i have the same @Entity class and save data via defauld CrudRepository method save(entity) so i can't choose what fields i want to update and what are not. The second idea is to remove that problematic field from the entity, create a new one entity which extends first and place that field there. After that, use the extended entity in cases where I want to interact with that field and the base entity in cases where I don't. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are both threads allowed to proceed, even if one doesn't see the changes made by the other one (in other words, is the data modified in one thread independent of the data modified in the other)?

If so, you could use `@DynamicUpdate`. This way, Hibernate will only update the fields that have in fact been modified, without overwriting any other fields. Please note that this comes with a performance penalty of its own, since it prevents Hibernate from using a single prepared statement for all updates to the entity.

If not, you can use locking to synchronize the threads.

Comment: Yep, I think @DynamicUpdate should work, but I have concerns about perfomance

Comment: Well, there's always a tradeoff between stricter isolation and performance. You would need to compare performance with respect to optimistic locking, for example. Also, if write contention is the issue, and it seems some properties are independent from others, perhaps the entity could be split into smaller, independent parts?